# for in loop in map not working as expected

Tags: flutter

I use this code to make actions according to the number of documents in a Firestore collection

```
   onPressed: () async {
         Map<String, dynamic> data = {};
       await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('primary').get().then((value) {
                       for (var i in value.docs){
                             data.addAll(i.data());
                         }
                      });
                          print(data);
                      }
```

The thing is that Im only storing in the map `data` the last document information

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your code is not working but you can try the `forEach` method:

```
     await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("primary")
      .get()
      .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
       // your code
    });
```

Good Luck!